# Tags in content builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder, tag

When I apply tags to any of my templates, content blocks, etc.

They do not save or there isn't a save button, is this a default or am I doing this incorrectly?

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted, so other users can see that your question has been answered correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to press the tab-key so the tag is displayed in a small rounded rectangle and has a X-icon on the right hand side  (see image below). If you just type the tag-name the tag isn't saved.

[image: correctly saved tags]

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the tags in tags admin? They must first be added to the tag library in order to add them. There's a defect in that the system isn't warning the user they're adding an invalid tag that will be fixed in an upcoming release.

To add tags, go to Administration -> Account -> Tags.